# Role authorization configuration in openAPI specs

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

We are creating openAPI for our services. These services are protected by the JWT token that is sent in the authorization header. In that JWT, we have claims related to roles. Depending on the role, the user can access the endpoint/path he is trying to access. Is there any way we can define the role to endpoint/path map in openAPI.

e.g I have an endpoint/path, /api/v1/users and this can be accessed by the user who has the role "ADMIN". How can I define this in my openAPI specs?